# CopyFile on a file with the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT attribute

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, symlink

I need to copy contents of one folder to another. I copy all files with the use of [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, which works great, unless there's a symbolic link in that folder (or the file system object with the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` attribute.) How do you copy it to a new location?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use [`SHFileOperation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) or [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx) to copy the entire folder instead of individual files?

Comment: So you mean you want to copy it as a link, not as a file?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I generally try to stay away from Shell APIs that take HWND -- I need it for a system service. But nonetheless I just tried it and they don't copy symbolic links as links. Instead I got an empty folder or a link, if it's a symbolic link to a file.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes. I want to keep them as symbolic links to whatever they were. I just realized that there's a bunch of types of symbolic links: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx